# Are mitochondria dead?

Tags: mitochondria, life

In [the video "What is Life? Is Death Real?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOCaacO8wus), the subject of mitochondria is raised at 2:58. At 3:12, the narrator says "[mitochondria] are not alive any more: they are dead."

What currents of thought lead to this affirmation?

When I search for [mitochondria are dead](https://www.google.ca/webhp?#q=mitochondria%20are%20dead) on Google, I get many links about the role of mitochondria in cell death, but I don't see anywhere that the assertion in this video is discussed.

Comment: idea probably is that mitochondria can't survive outside the host cell.

Comment: @aaaaaa: That seems a strange qualification, since most (probably all) organisms can't survive outside the environment they're adapted to.  Humans, for instance, die pretty quick if you don't provide them with oxygen and keep them between roughly -50°-50°C.

Comment: See [this related post](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20437/are-sperms-considered-living/20455)

Comment: @jamesqf SolarLunix made a great point, please consider accepting it

Comment: also, i find all question like "what is life"useless in our fight against death and disease.

Comment: Does it really matter why some Youtuber decided they are alive or not? Clearly an argument can be made for them being alive (have DNA, replicate, process chemicals) and not being alive (cannot survive very long outside cells, not very complex) and it comes down to an arbitrary distinction. It's an irrelevant concern, nothing about your (or anyone's) life would change if the Czar of Science decreed one way or another.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.4803 "...determining which phase (non-life or life) a given system is in requires dynamical information and therefore can only be inferred by identifying causal architecture."

Comment: related: [*Can you consider a human as alive, or is it the cells on the body that are alive?*](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7053/can-you-consider-a-human-as-alive-or-is-it-the-cells-on-the-body-that-are-alive)

Comment: You should restate the argument given in the video in your question (to make it more self-contained), and highlight what parts you find unclear. At the moment, I think the question is unclear, and answers will mostly depend on how you define the terms **alive**, **dead**, and **life** (you haven't included working definitions of these concepts in your question).

Answer (score 38):

SolarLunix posted [an excellent answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/36547/948) detailing the criteria for being classified as "alive", and showed that by those criteria, mitochondria could be considered as "dead".

However, I would argue that the narrator's statement in your video does not make any sense. The currently-accepted theory of the evolution of mitochondria (and possibly other organelles) from free-living [prokaryotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prokaryote) is called [symbiogenesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbiogenesis) and postulates that the mitochondrial progenitors began living symbiotically with the precursors to [eukaryotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eukaryote) some 1.5 billion years ago. Life originated on Earth about 3.5 billion years ago, so eukaryotic cells (carrying mitochondria) have been around for a little less than half of that time.

In that incredibly large span of time (if you counted 1 number per second, you'd reach 1.5 billion in about 47.5 years), what used to be an independent organism (we assume) has become an organelle - an integral part of the eukaryotic cell. It absolutely could not survive outside the cell on its own, and relies on signals from the cell (mainly, the cell's energy needs as detected by "sensor" proteins to key molecules like glucose and ATP) to reproduce.

Therefore, it is most appropriate to think of mitochondria simply as another organelle, just like the endoplasmic reticulum, lysosomes, or the nucleus. It doesn't make sense to think of those other structures as "alive" or "dead", just as it doesn't make sense to think of mitochondria in the same way. Yes, they *used* to be independent, but are no longer; instead they are a well-integrated part of the whole cell.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Though here's an interesting observation: individual human cells are alive, but individual human organs are not. Both are constituent parts of the human organism, and individual cells are even strongly dependent on the rest of the body. Our individual cells have evolved from their ancient independent forms into the super-symbiotic system of the modern body. They form structures (organs) which are not alive, but those structures combine to form something that is alive. The longer I stare at this strange system, the less inclined I am to care about the definition of life.

Comment: So, long story short, they are no more "dead" as a part of a cell, than, let's say, liver as a part of human body? Do I get your meaning right?

Comment: @Mołot correct. We don't think of the liver, or spleen, or lungs as "alive" or "dead", and it doesn't make sense to think of organelles in that regard as well.

Answer (score 14):

**Short answer:** According to the [definition of life](http://www.biology-online.org/dictionary/Life), yes, [Mitochondria](http://www.biologyreference.com/Ma-Mo/Mitochondrion.html) are "dead".

---

**To be considered alive an organism must meet the following criteria:**

> - organized structure performing a specific function
> - an ability to sustain existence, e.g. by nourishment
> - an ability to respond to stimuli or to its environment
> - capable of adapting
> - an ability to germinate or reproduce

---

**Are Mitochondria organised?**

Yes, they have a structure that allows them to metabolise energy brought to it by the cell.

**Can Mitochondria sustain their own existence?**

No, many of the genes that mitochondria need to function are no longer in the mitochondria. They need the host cell to provide much of what they need for them.

Note that I am pointing to the Mitochondria's genetics. They used to be included in the Mitochondria itself and have been moved into the cell host DNA. This is why I consider them to be "dead" because they are no longer their own organism, they are an organelle that helps the cell stay alive.

We can stop here since this disqualifies Mitochondria from being considered alive. However, for completion, I will continue.

**Can Mitochondria respond to stimuli?**

Yes, in order for it to divide it receives signalling from the cell. I would consider this a response to its environment.

**Can Mitochondria reproduce?**

Yes, their reproduction is much like a bacteria reproduces - through a process called [fission](http://youtu.be/hOyUcjqcGpQ).

---

**Conclusion:** Since Mitochondria cannot sustain existence, alone (thanks to no longer holding their full genome) they are dead.

Comment: This question seems like a (meaningless) exercise in semantics. By this logic, then my skin and heart are "dead", since they can't sustain their own existence.

Comment: The issue I am having is that it seems like you have gone from "Not alive" to "Is dead". Are all things that are not alive dead?  Eg the sun is not alive, but I would not call it dead. A spoon is not alive, but also not dead  (Also Cthulu :-P).
I feel like to be dead you means be "not alive" and also "previously was alive."
(whether previously alive refers to individuals or not I am not so sure.)

Comment: -1. By your logic, parasites such as tapeworms (which can't survive outside their hosts) are dead.

Comment: @Oxinabox Btw.. I can argue that sun is alive :P.. It is self sustaining and perhaps will some day die.. It is organized and can adapt to stimuli (at the celestial level of course). Earth is alive too that way.. **SolarLunix**: Actually every living organism is living only with respect to its environment. Heterotrophs are dependent on autotrophs (but we cannot call them dead, can we)

Comment: I do think that "sustain their own existence" is a remarkably high bar, of which I am unaware of any member of any species attaining.  Humans, for instance, do not survive long in the cold vacuum of space without anything sustaining them.  Most every biology text I am aware of recognizes that we live in a network, not in isolation.

Comment: Just move one comma in your conclusion: "since mitochondria cannot sustain existence, alone they are dead". Inside cells, on the other hand, party on. Anyway, I think you're using a definition of "a living organism" or "a form of life" (and even then one has to be generous as regards independence, as others have noted). It doesn't imply a definition of "dead" that is or sensibly can be applied to parts of living organisms.

Comment: @Sparhawk but unlike Mitochondria, your skin and heart have the genetics to survive on their own.

Comment: @MarchHo but unlike Mitochondria, tapeworms have their full genetics and their offspring can move into a different host. Mitochondria are stuck in the same host lineage from generation 1 to generation infinity.

Comment: @SolarLunix That argument is not consistent with the points in your answer.

Comment: @Sparhawk I specifically pointed out the genetics as to why they are not able to survive on their own. I made it clearer since the point wasn't obvious. I can edit again if you still think I wasn't clear enough on that point.

Comment: @CortAmmon it does seem like a remarkably high bar, but I was t looking at putting them in another place so much as I was looking at them in relation to what they used to be. Because all of their genetics are no longer located within them anymore I don't consider them an organism, just an organelle.

Comment: @SteveJessop done, thanks. You made a good point.

Comment: @Oxinabox
I think that when talking about biology, you're either dead or alive. anything in between if caused by our lack of understanding. The sun cannot be analysed in the same manner as a plant (if you pick the sun then i would pick any random rock. Is it alive?)
Why isn't the sun alive if it fits all the given criteria except reproduction  - which, if we wanna be picky about it, then mules are dead.
So, the way i see it, the first distinction to be made is whether we are talking inanimate or not.

Comment: @SolarLunix If one wishes to look at "what they were" to develop a subjective position on whether they are alive, that is fine.  I just find it important to note that any argument which claims to have declare the livingness or deadness of something to be "case closed" runs into trouble with definitions.  The line between them is not as crisp as we may wish.  For example, instead of "sustains existence," Wikipedia has "metabolism," which a mitochondria clearly has.

Comment: The *sustain its own existance* part is too vague to make sense. Everything requires an ecosystem to sustain it: we can't sustain ourselves without food! Many vitamins, amino acids,  etc. Cannot be made by the human body because we lack genes for that; so are we not-alive like the mitochondrea?

Comment: @Sparhawk skin and heart cannot survive on their own. The component cells need things that are made by others. And it's not just a matter of being switched off, as no cell in the human body can make vitamin C, as the gene for that has been moved out to the "host" eco*system* at large.  Out genetics are no longer located within our cells, in exactly the same manner  as SolarLinux points out for mitochondrea.

Comment: @JDługosz : "Our genetics are no longer located within our cells..." that is subtle and frightening!

Answer (score 12):

I would like to expand a bit on SolarLunix's post, because the logic used in the conclusion would also mean that endosymbionts, such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchnera_(bacterium), who cannot survive outside their host are also "dead".

I think many of us disagree with that notion, so instead I would say that it's the fact that so many of their genes have been relocated to the nucleus that makes them organelles and thus substructures of the eukaryotic cell and thus "dead".

Ultimately though, I think it's more a matter of semantics, since you could argue that they represent an advanced stage of endosymbiosis.

Comment: Agreed. And if we're moved just a few miles (straight up or down) from our environment, we survive just as poorly as various endosymbionts.

Comment: That's what I was saying that everyone seems to have missed....

Comment: @user2338816 or a few thousand north or south

Answer (score 5):

What a brilliant question for promoting a discussion.  Mitochondria definitely reproduce, they maintain a better energy flow than any other part of the cell, and they maintain a very low entropy state by exploiting that energy flow.  It may not be a textbook answer but being alive really is about decreasing your local entropy by exploiting a flow of energy.  I suspect that mitochondria have ceased to change under the pressures of natural selection, but so what - they have been practically perfect for a billion years.

Comment: Jeremy England's hypothesis that life arises naturally as a way to capture energy and dissipate it as heat: https://www.quantamagazine.org/20140122-a-new-physics-theory-of-life/